# How to align two elements at each ends in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, alignment

I need to show two labels "hello" and "world", one at leftmost, and the other at right most.
How can I do that?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="300">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left">Hello</Label>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right">World</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Width="300">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left">Hello</Label>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right">World</Label>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How about some columns though

Comment: Well, it'll get very messy if it's sized down like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Grid Width="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0">Hello</Label>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">World</Label>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DockPanel

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Width="300">
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left">Hello</Label>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Right">World</Label>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```